# Visual Studio 2013 showing hidden files in solution explorer incorrectly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Even though I have the "Show All Files" turned off, solution explorer is showing hidden files and files not part of the project (generated JavaScript files from TypeScript for example).  I've clicked this on and off again many times to no effect.  Any suggested solutions?

Comment: What files, specifically? Can you post a screenshot? Note that Show all Files is per-project, not per-solution, and doesn't have effect in Website projects,

Comment: @Dai, you actually solved what turned out to be a silly question.  I always had focus on the solution when I clicked the show all files button, but when I went to the project in question, it worked.  My bad, but post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as such.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Show All Files" button in Solution Explorer works on a per-project basis: toggling the button will only affect the visibility of files under the Project node which is the parent of the currently selected (or last-selected) file, which understandably might lead to user-unexpected behaviour (personally I would redesign the Solution Explorer to have 2 toolbars: one for solution-wide options, and the other, positioned below, for per-project options.

Some projects don't have a concept of "included" or "excluded" files, such as "Website projects" (as opposed to "Web Application projects"), where all files in the filesystem are visible in the tree-view - or in Visual C++ projects where the Show All Files button switches to a 'virtual' project view with artificial groupings as folders (Headers, Sources, Resources, etc) instead of filesystem directories.